# How to use apache pig filter to find '.PDF'

Tags: apache-pig

I have a file `/pigmix.txt` in HDFS which have a list of files with different format like `.PDF`,`.DOC`,`.PPT` etc. I want to filter only `.PDF`. How can I use apache pig filter function for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try the below **filter** command?

**input:**

```
file1.txt
file2.PDF
file3.doc
file4.ppt
file5.pdf
```

**PigScript:**

```
A = LOAD 'input' USING PigStorage() AS (filename:chararray);
B = FILTER A BY filename matches '.*\\.(pdf|PDF)$';
DUMP B;
```

**Output:**

```
(file2.PDF)
(file5.pdf)
```